# Text to Column on column containing dates using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert a column containing dates from Text to Column as it is currently not in date format. I can easily do this on Excel. However, facing challenges to do properly on VBA.

I have tried multiple codes. However, they are converting only some cells of the column to date format but not converting all.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells
.TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
End With
```

Comment: Write `debug.print ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B").address` to see what should be changed.

Comment: Thanks Vityata. However, this is no affecting the output. I am getting the same result.

Comment: What is it giving in the immediate window? Press `control + G` and see there.

Comment: In the immediate window, it shows me the dates in the respective cells only. However, can't distinguish the format here. Reason being - format is same when it comes to display. This is data downloaded from a tool. When I apply filter on the column and click on filter drop down, it shows dates in "dd-mm-yyyy" format for each case. However, if I apply Text to Filter using Excel, it shows Year and then month as sub part and dates.... in the filter drop down.                                                                    I want to apply the same using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, make it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

With ActiveSheet.Range("B:" & lastRow(column_to_check:=2))

    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
End with
End Sub

Public Function lastRow(Optional str_sheet As String, Optional column_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet  As Worksheet

        If str_sheet = vbNullString Then
            Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Else
            Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(str_sheet)
        End If

    lastRow = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, column_to_check).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

The lastRow function returns the last row in the column_to_check. In your case, the second column.

Comment: Hi Vtyata, it is still the same output. Also, want to mention that it is not converting initial half cells or the last few ones. However, my code is converting correctly some random cells in the column and not affecting the remaining ones.

Comment: If you do it manually, do you succeed to convert them correctly? If yes, just record the macro.

Comment: Yes, Manually it worked. I had tried recording that Macro too. However, when I ran the macro, again it could convert only some random cells in the column but not all the cells in the column.   :(

Comment: Though this has not got resolved yet. However, I am really thankful for you being constantly trying to help me out..

Comment: Ok, so what happens when you record the macro and change them manually? When you run the recorded macro it does not work?

Comment: It works. However, it doesn't convert the format of all cells in the column but does convert the format for some random cells in the column.

Comment: So, when you run it manually it works, but when you run the macro it does not work completely? And what happens when you record a macro and run it?

Comment: When I record the macro and then run it, it doesn't convert the format of all cells in the column but does convert the format for some random cells in the column.`

Comment: Ok, but while recording it, it does format everything as expected?

Comment: **Yes**, it does format as expected while I do it using Excel Function "Text to Columns" from the Excel ribbon and simultaneously recording the macro.